# Should I be worried if the total number of processes is approaching nproc limit?

Tags: process

Can this be damaging to the system in any way? Or will this just slow the system down?

I could increase the nproc limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and reboot, but I really don't want to reboot the system.

Comment: There should also be a run-time entry somewhere in `/proc/`.

Answer (score 0):

On my system all the `nproc` entries are commented out. I assume yours has been configured in some way.

The `nproc` setting is enforced per user or group member. The limits are implemented during logon or session start via PAM's `pam_limits.so` module. This means that you can change `/etc/security/limits.h` and it will apply from the next session or login.